# Execution time performance when counting up to 1,000,000,000

Tags: performance

I have made a simple C++ program that simply counts up a variable to 1,000,000,000 and then displays the time it took. I used a simple for loop to do this.

```
for(long n=0;n<1000000000;n++);
```

The time it took is about 22 seconds. This confuses me a little, because the pi operates at 700Mhz and the program used about 96% of the cpu. Why didn't this take about 2 seconds? Does increasing an integer by 1 take 10 clock cycles in this case? I have previously worked with AVR microprocessors and this was a reasonably good way to estimate the speed in those cases. I didn't use any optimization flags when I compiled the code, and the OS I used is Rasbian.

Comment: Try a realtime distro like RiscOS and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @ppumkin Probably not; my `real` time was only a 1/4 second greater than the combined `sys` and `user` time. The pi was otherwise idle excepting daemon processes that do intermittent polling (at least one at 5 second intervals).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The time it took is about 22 seconds.

Yep.  Took 21.7s on a pi here.

> Does increasing an integer by 1 take 10 clock cycles in this case?

Hopefully not, but that's not all that's going on.  You're also making a comparison each time to evaluate the for loop conditional.

No more than 1 assembly instruction can be processed per cycle, and I believe it may often be less than that, e.g., if the instruction requires fetching or storing stuff from/to RAM.  I'm not at all an assembly level guy, but I can show you some clues about what's involved.  It's easier if we break that loop down a bit, although the assembly generated won't be quite the same:

```
int main (void) {
        long i = 0;
        while (1) {
                i++;
                if (i > 1000000000) break;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Now compile that with debugging symbols: `g++ -g test.cpp`, then load it into the debugger: `gdb ./a.out`.  At the prompt, type `disassemble/m main`.  You should get a few dozen lines of output including this:

```
3               while (1) {
   0x000083fc <+24>:    nop                     ; (mov r0, r0)

4                       i++;
   0x00008400 <+28>:    ldr     r3, [r11, #-8]
   0x00008404 <+32>:    add     r3, r3, #1
   0x00008408 <+36>:    str     r3, [r11, #-8]

5                       if (i > 1000000000) break;
   0x0000840c <+40>:    ldr     r2, [r11, #-8]
   0x00008410 <+44>:    ldr     r3, [pc, #28]   ; 0x8434 <main()+80>
   0x00008414 <+48>:    cmp     r2, r3
   0x00008418 <+52>:    ble     0x83fc <main()+24>
   0x0000841c <+56>:    nop                     ; (mov r0, r0)

6               }
```

The numbers in the left column correspond to line numbers from the source.  Notice line 4, `i++` -- incrementing an integer by one -- is three lines of assembly (each is one instruction).  Line 5, checking the same condition as the `for()` loop, is 5 lines of assembly.

The compiler can be made a bit smarter, which should help to speed things up.  If you throw in the `-O2` switch (2nd level of optimization), i.e., `g++ -g -O2 test.cpp`, it will spot the fact that this loop does nothing, and that's what it will then do: nothing.  If you look at the assembly as per above, there won't be any for that loop, and:

```
> time ./a.out
real 0m0.016s
user 0m0.010s
sys  0m0.000s
```

Quite a performance improvement ;)  Of course it wasn't really counting anything this time.

Comment: Silly me to not look at the assembly code! It totally makes sense now that I know how many instructions it takes for one iteration in the loop. Thank you!

Comment: in `disassemble\m main` the slash should be the other way `/`